# Queryset with entries that have related objects

Tags: python, django

I want to take all entries that have related objects

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I want to do a queryset that take all the authors that have at least one book.

I did the logic in template to show only if _set.all.count != 0 like this

views.py

```
Author.objects.all()
```

.html

```
if author.books_set.all.count != 0
```

But the pagination is showing incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

Try using `filter()` when you fetch the items in `views.py`.

```py
Author.objects.filter(book_set__count__gt=0)
```

And you don't need the logic in your template.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but it is not working! Cannot resolve keyword 'books_set' into field.

Comment: Try: `book_set` 
It is related_name in `Book` model to `Author`